# Cannot find ld when non-root user

Tags: 14.04, permissions, c++, clang

I have an autocompile program available on a website that I am running. The program uses clang++-3.5 to compile C++. When I run the auto-compile python script, as a root user, compilation is successful. However, when I run it from the website using the same input, the script gets this output from clang++-3.5:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Executable "ld" doesn't exist!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ld` may not be in your users `$PATH`.

Try `whereis ld` to locate the command

and `echo $PATH` to see if the folder is listed.

It's usual for a non `sudo`'d command to not find it for simple security I believe. for e.g my remote box doesn't find `ifconfig` for non `sudo` commands by default.

From [a post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux) about setting $PATH

> You need to add it to your `~/.profile file`.
>
> `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir`
>
> Depending on what you're doing, you also may want to `symlink` to
>   binaries:
>
> ```
> cd /usr/bin
> sudo ln -s /path/to/binary binary-name
> ```

Comment: Where possible don't just add link, copy the relevant information and leave a link to give credit. This time, I did it for you.

Comment: @markkirby That is a better way (noted for future), was just giving the other guy credit.

Comment: Still give the credcit :) but include the information too, just incase the site linked cannot be found